# Ldap server cannot accept Public IP

Tags: networking, iptables, ldap, openldap

I have this LDAP server and 10 clients in the network. 2 clints can connect to server using server's private ip (10.10.10.10), but the other clients cannot ping private ip, so they use public ip instead (ex: 202.xxx.xxx.xxx). But, when they connect with public ip, the server rejected, because of the port blocking or something. I added this three lines in iptables config to open port 389. but unfortunately the clients still cannot connect to ldap server.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 389 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 636 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9830 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: The typical problem is that the `-A` flag appends new rules to the existing rule-set and the existing rule-set had a final rule rejecting everything not specifically opened already, which means the new rules will never be applicable... - Investigate with `iptables -L -v -n`

Comment: As HBruijn said, we need to see everything that is set in iptables first. Another question, you said that there are 10 clients in the network. Are all 10 clients on the same 10.x.x.x network? If so, your real problem can likely be resolved without having the internal clients access the server from the WAN. To assist you with that however, we will certainly need the entire contents of iptables.